# High blood pressure can lead to anxiety?

Tags: neurophysiology, anxiety

I know that anxiety leads to high blood pressure due to elevations of adrenaline.

It also can also increase cortisol levels which as [the Mayo Clinic points out](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/stress-management/in-depth/stress/art-20046037):

- curbs functions that would be nonessential or detrimental in a fight-or-flight situation
- alters immune system responses
- increases sugars (glucose) in the bloodstream and
- suppresses the digestive system, the reproductive system and growth processes.

According to Jayne Leonard in Medical News Today ([2019](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/327212)):

> having long-term high blood pressure — which doctors refer to as hypertension — can cause people to feel anxious about their health and future.

And, while interestingly she points out that:

> some medications for anxiety can increase blood pressure

I am not talking about fears about health after being diagnosed with high blood pressure due to [arterial atherosclerosis](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/atherosclerosis/) for example.

**What I am referring to is the possibility of stress/anxiety being caused by the high blood pressure**, maybe creating an elevation of adrenaline or cortisol through some kind of neural connection with the heart and blood supply.

Is this possible?

Anxiety can lead to [aggression](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/stress-anxiety-depression/controlling-anger/) and/or other behaviours — as an example (as @starckman pointed out in the comments) there is a study by Kouchaki & Desai ([2015](https://doi.org/10.1037/a0037796)) that showed a link between anxiety and unethical behavior in the workplace — and **I was wondering if high blood pressure not caused by mental health problems could lead to those mental health problems and possibly elevate the blood pressure problems in a vicious cycle**.

### References

Kouchaki, M., & Desai, S. D. (2015). Anxious, threatened, and also unethical: How anxiety makes individuals feel threatened and commit unethical acts. *Journal of Applied Psychology, 100*(2), 360–375. https://doi.org/10.1037/a0037796

Leonard, J. (2019). What is the link between anxiety and high blood pressure? *Medical News Today* https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/327212

Comment: In the link for "aggression", I didn't find the statement that "Anxiety can lead to aggression", although I am very curious to know the link between the two. Thanks for your question btw

Comment: I can see what you mean @starckman - it is not mentioned in the strict sense - but it does elude to it when saying *"Support is also available if you're finding it hard to cope with stress, anxiety or depression"*. I will try and find a more direct link to it

Comment: There is a study that showed a link between anxiety and unethical behavior in the workplace (https://psycnet.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037%2Fa0037796)

Answer (score 1):

Neuroticism can lead to hostility:

- [Egan & Lewis (2011): "Neuroticism and agreeableness differentiate emotional and narcissistic expressions of aggression"](https://www.academia.edu/download/41438138/Neuroticism_and_agreeableness_differenti20160122-10012-16dfc06.pdf)

> A key finding in this study is the influence of N on a variety of
> distress types; Suls and Martin (2005) have observed the ‘neurotic
> cascade’ produced by N. Hyper-reactivity, differential exposure to
> negative events because of the environments high-N persons select and
> create for themselves, differential appraisal for events (e.g.,
> perceiving experiences as more troubling than they really are),
> negative emotional transfer, and problems changing maladaptive ways of
> coping with distress and challenges **all combine to upset a high-N
> person, which may make them hostile**. However, high N does not drive
> outwardly directed narcissistic aggression.

However, I am not clear about the difference between anxiety and neuroticism, as well as between hostility and aggression.

### References

Egan, V., & Lewis, M. (2011). Neuroticism and agreeableness differentiate emotional and narcissistic expressions of aggression. *Personality and Individual Differences, 50*(6), 845-850. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.paid.2011.01.007

Comment: Thanks for the link. While your link is interesting, it doesn't really answer my question - please see my question with more emphasis on what I am actually asking

Comment: @ChrisRogers understood